# Can one presently register a new flying car in the US as an aircraft and as an automobile?

Tags: faa-approval

Can one presently register a flying car in the US as an aircraft and as an automobile?

I understand there is a 1956 Taylor Aircar for sale which is registered and seems to have an automotive license plate.
This may be grandfathered. Source: Aerocarforsale.com

[image]

What about a new flying car?

Assuming one can get insurance for both modes, can one presently register one physical flying car as two entities, one as an aircraft, which is registered federally, and one as an automobile, which is registered by state?

Comment: I'd think it's not going to pass as street legal, since its wing span does not fit into a lane, perhaps a few other requirements too. Does the source show what license plate it has?

Comment: @void_ptr Google the Aerocar.  You park the wings, tail, and propeller at the airport, drive around in the "cabin" with its four wheels.  Come back to the 'port, reconnect, preflight etc. and fly away.  On the road, it's like a compact car (very compact for the 1950s).

Comment: @Fred there are a couple companies selling these now, and another in development -- Terrafugia (or whatever they're called now since being sold to a Chinese firm) had gone some way toward FAA and DOT acceptance (the latter the crux for registration as a car) before the after-purchase round of redesigns started.

Comment: They are always lousy cars and lousy airplanes.  Like amphibious vehicles.  You use it because you absolutely must have the capability and can live with the crappiness.

Comment: @JohnK It appears that no one absolutely had to have this capability.  BTW some amphib IFVs are pretty good vehicles, but of course they aren't boats at all.